# SQL referencing foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I can't get the `GenreID` foreign key on the `Album` table to work. Anyone know why?

```
CREATE TABLE ArtistBand 
(
     ArtistID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     BandName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     NameOfMembers VARCHAR(255),
     NumberOfMembers INT
);

CREATE TABLE Genre
(
     GenreID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     GenreType VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     AlbumID INT,
     FOREIGN KEY(AlbumID) REFERENCES Album(AlbumID)
);

CREATE TABLE Album 
(
    AlbumID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    ReleaseDate DATE NOT NULL,
    Producers VARCHAR (255),
    ArtistID INT,
    GenreID INT,

    FOREIGN KEY(ArtistID) REFERENCES ArtistBand(ArtistID),
    FOREIGN KEY (GenreID) REFERENCES Genre (GenreID)
);
```

Comment: Can you share some error output with us?

Comment: May be first create tables and then alter table to add foreign keys.

Comment: The circular foreign key references between `Album` and `Genre` will cause you some trouble. `AlbumID` makes no sense in `Genre`. The relation *from* `Album` will do the trick, unless you really expect only a single `Album` in each `Genre`

Comment: Hello Aaron welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer much faster – Also 
please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Looks like MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the circular foreign key reference between `Genre` and `Album`. Logically speaking, the reference from `Genre` to `Album` doesn't make any sense anyway :).

```
CREATE TABLE ArtistBand (
ArtistID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
BandName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
NameOfMembers VARCHAR(255),
NumberOfMembers INT
);

CREATE TABLE Genre(
GenreID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
GenreType VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Album (
AlbumID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
ReleaseDate DATE NOT NULL,
Producers VARCHAR (255),
ArtistID INT,
GenreID INT,
FOREIGN KEY(ArtistID) REFERENCES ArtistBand(ArtistID),
FOREIGN KEY (GenreID) REFERENCES Genre (GenreID)
);
```

Comment: @Aaron did it solve your problem. If yes, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks heaps! that worked, i know this is not a piratical bit of code just a project we had to do for school

Answer (score 0):

if use sql server : auto_increment be modified to identity

```
CREATE TABLE ArtistBand (
ArtistID INT identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
BandName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
NameOfMembers VARCHAR(255),
NumberOfMembers INT
);

CREATE TABLE Genre(
GenreID INT identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
GenreType VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Album (
AlbumID INT identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
ReleaseDate DATE NOT NULL,
Producers VARCHAR (255),
ArtistID INT,
GenreID INT,
FOREIGN KEY(ArtistID) REFERENCES ArtistBand(ArtistID),
FOREIGN KEY (GenreID) REFERENCES Genre (GenreID)
);
```